# Encrypting asymmetrically only a part of a large file

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, public-key-encryption

I want to store a large file on a publicly accessible service, amazon, bittorrent, ipfs etc.
I want this file to be encrypted.
I know the common practice is to encrypt the file symmetrically with a complex password and then encrypt the password with the recipient public key, but I have a use case I need to deliver the key to each recipient so when the password leaks to public I know who did it.

So what I thought of was to encrypt the whole file with AES CBC then split it to chunks and encrypt only the first chunk asymmetrically.

Are there any logical mistakes in this idea? What should be the minimum size of the first chunk (in bytes or percentage of the whole file) so it's safe to say without decrypting the first one there is no way to decrypt the remaining ones.

## Edit

Thanks for the answers
I'll elaborate a little more on the use case.

I'm planning to let users put (sell) files on decentralised storage using my platform (and I have no control over the nodes - lets assume it's global ipfs). To be compliant with the regulations files has to be encrypted and I have to have a way to block the access to it.
Because as stated before I wont be able to delete the files from all the nodes I thought of encrypting the files asymmetrically but this requires preparing a separate copy for each recipient and would take a lot of time.

That's how I came up with the idea of encrypting only a part of the file, moreover this would be done by a re-encryption proxy so the seller would only need to prepare the re-encryption key and the amount of excessive data on the network would be minimal (only one shard per buyer).

Still when the authorities approach me that I'm sharing illegal content I could tell them the file is encrypted and the only guys that downloaded it are these public keys owners.

Comment: Research digital watermarks. Your problem is not an encryption application.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently some things are misunderstood

> have a use case I need to deliver the key to each recipient so when the password leaks to public I know who did it.

Lets assume the file is encrypted with a single symetric encryption key (password in ypur case) . You may encrypt the password using recipients' personal public key, but once the password is released, you have no means to find out who leaked/released it.

> split it to chunks and encrypt only the first chunk asymmetrically

that makes no sense / reason (at least I did not find any reason why this would help you to achive the stated use case)

note: the reason why hybrid encryption is used is that asymmetric encryption (RSA) is feasible to encrypt only limited amount of data (e. g. symmetric encr. key)

Answer (score 1):

your problem is not solvable by the means of classic cryptography

when we take a look at your problem one might think your usecase is like so often in cryptography: confidentiality, but it is not

confidentiality in a cryptographic context means: helping n parties to keep a secret

that means, all of the original n parties share the common interest of keeping that secret ...

in your case, you suspect at least one of the parties not to share this interest ... this is where classical crypto attempts will fail to solve your problem ...

pay tv companies learned this the hard way ... their solution seemingly is to replace the content keys faster than a group of rouge actors can share the needed keys for live decryption and to manage access to the content keys by encrypting them with group keys, which are partitioned and distributet along all legitimate clients ... that only "works" (read "not really if you put in enough effort") for large dynamic content streams, not for a static file ...

your use case sounds more like digital watermarking and fingerprinting